# Any way to power a 5V relay with software?

Tags: audio, motherboard, power, relay

I have a relay that can be powered by a 5V output and I'm trying to power it in software on a PC motherboard.

**Question:** How to I get a 5V output from any part of the motherboard (prefferable accessible from the outside of the case) and control it programmatically with any programming language?

---

Output doesn't have to be exactly 5V because I tested the relay and it works perfectly even with 3V.

The best method appears to be using a Parralel port, but none of my machines have it.

DVI somehow maybe? PS2? 3.5 mm jack? Just anything that can produce a few volts on demand.

---

NOTE: The computer will NOT be used for anything other than powering the relay so sacrifices for features are accepted.

NOTE2: The audio jack (3.5 mm) seems promising. Can it output some volts when I play a sine wave or something?

The reason I'm doing this instead of using my Raspberry Pi or Arduino is because my Computer Science theacher really wants this to be completely free, and plans on using a patched version of Windows XP to use a paralel port in combination with some DOS program. Which I think is insane.

And if you're wondering the relay powers the school bell.

Comment: The traditional solution is to use the paralel port. Sadly its interface seems to be missing from some modern motheraboards (thougb both my new skylake build do have a connector for it on their motherboard). Can you check if it is present on yours?

Comment: Other than that: Yes, using XP in  thios day and age is insane.

Comment: @Hennes I don't want to use it not being present in modern motherboards. I don't have it either.

Comment: Isn't USB 5v? As far as I know, it *may* be possible to disable power to a USB device using devcon ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544707%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ) adn a command like `devcon.exe disable "USB\VID_8087&PID_0024"` I HAVE NOT TESTED THIS

Comment: This is an insane project - the cost of powering a PC for a year or 2 is more then the cost of an Raspberry Pi, let alone arduino - both of which are designed with GPIO pins to do exactly what you are after.   You might be able to jerry rig something up to an RS232 (Serial) port or serial port, but, without interfacing hardware [ more expensive then an Arduino] its hit and miss.

Comment: You don't say how much current the relay needs.  That may determine where you can get it from.  A way to increase your options is to build a small electronic gadget to act as the switch that powers the relay (the whole thing powered from an external brick, if necessary).  Then you can trigger it with a digital signal from many potential ports.  However, davidgo is onto something.

Comment: Aye. At no current cost and long term are at odds.

Comment: @davidgo Yeah, tell that to my Computer Science teacher. (I 110% agree with you)

Comment: "The reason I'm doing this instead of using my Raspberry Pi or Arduino is because my Computer Science theacher really wants this to be completely free,"  So it's not "free" if you want to use a $35 RaspPi computer, but it IS "free" if you use a multi-hundred dollar+ Windows computer?  I think your Comp Sci teacher may need to revisit the "logic" section of his education.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I don't think any students in the school like him. I'll try to convince him to go for an Arduino.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: Old, unused computer on-hand = $0.  Old, unused relay on-hand = $0.  Buy RaspPi = $35.  $35 > $0.  School budget = $0, so $35 = $infinite.

Comment: @fixer Old RaspBerryPi on-hand = $0 (hell I've got 2 or 3 collecting rust). So if I was in the class I could just use a RaspPi?  :)

Comment: Actually, this question is very illuminating. It raises a concern now useless modern PCs become. To remind, the "PC" stands for Personal Computer, if anyone still remember. The PCs can't even perform the elementary function as tuning on a relay, not speaking about hidden partitions and secret directories that you, a PC owner, have no rights to access. The PC has transformed into annoying advertising kiosk for merchants.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets split this question into three parts:

1. How to I get a 5V output from any part of the motherboard (preferable accessible from the outside of the case)
2. How to control it programmatically?
3. How do do this completely free.

Lest start with the last. That is a no go. You need to isolate the external power (the one to the bell) from the computers internal setup.  That means that you want a relais and some glue logic.  That might not cost much, but it is not going to be completely free.

Also [pre-made solutions](https://www.sossolutions.nl/2xusbrelais?fee=4&fep=820?utm_source=shopping&utm_medium=adwords&utm_term=2%20x%20Relais%2012Volt%20USB%20NO%20/%20NC&utm_campaign=shopping&gclid=CKrqydqN_s4CFVFgfgod27oCNQ) start around €8,50. The one I linked to explecitly mentions being compatible with a rPi, but as I read the specs it seems to work with any USB output.

Creating sunch a device might be a fun project, but resources used, potential computers blow up (well, short circuited, not likely exploding) and time invested means that buying such a device is the **economical** way to go.

I stressed economical since its counterpoint is if you want to learn the most from this rather than get to an end product.

That leaves two more points:

Item 2: How do I control it depends on the implementation. USB seems nice (and +5v at 100mili-Ampere might be enough to drive a relais) but as far as I know there is no way to control it. There is `devcon` which can be used to enable, disable or reset a device but other posts here on [SU] mention that this does **not** remove the power part.

Item 1: How to get +5 volt is also interesting: USB barely delivers any power. It should only feed have to 100mA. Just enough for some control logic, enabling USB devices to identify themselves and ask for more power. Quite a few USB implementations are broken, but you do risk things burning out if you simply connect to USB and tap its power. That leaves only three other common sources of power: 1) The +5 power from the desktops PSU,  2) Power from fan headers  3) Power freom powered eSATA plugs. (not sure about there, they might suffer from the same limits as USB).

Update from Ali Chen' comments:
*No. This is for a DEVICE that must not use more than 100mA before enumeration and configuration. But any USB HOST MUST PROVIDE 500mA no matter what.*

*Not "some implementations". These are two separate requirements. The only case for the 100mA formal budgeting limit is only for a special class of "bus powered hubs"*

Note that the last may include the USB powered hub on a rPi.

Recap and conclusions:

- You will need some power source for the bell. Most likely not from the computer itself but from an externalal PSU. That one draws power, so you want to switch that off when not in use.
- Same for the PC. If it happens to be on all the time: fine. If not it will waste much more power than buying a rPi and gadgets costs.
- You want to separate the power to the bell from the PC. That means a relais and a sane setup.
- Preferably you want a second one to power of the bells PSU (which is probably connected to +240v or whatever comes from your local wallsocket).
- You want to do this safely.

Economical conclusion: Buy a fricking rPi and pre-made board. Learn the important lesson when to home brew and when not to.

... all under the assumption that this is a real world project and not something which you only need to design for educational purposes. If it is educational start with a desktop PC, triple crossfire. A graphics benchmark which triggers at certain times... and an IR meter in the exhaust to know when to trigger. The rest of that implementation is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Regarding VBUS USB power: 100mA is absolutely wrong. On a regular PC mainboard the VBUS on USB connectors will deliver much more than that. Any USB port MUST provide at least 500mA, by USB specifications. In fact, any individual USB port  on modern PC mainboard will deliver up to 2A, since it is usually connected to +5VSB power of system Power Supply, which is, by ATX12 standard, 2A minimum. Never underestimate the power of USB :-)

Comment: Some implementation may provide more than the minimum required. OK. Valid. But any most provide... not sure sure. The target device MUST ask if it want more than 1 (100mW) bin of power. it MAY be granted, or it may be declined.

Comment: No. This is for a DEVICE that must not use more than 100mA before enumeration and configuration. But any USB HOST MUST PROVIDE 500mA no matter what. Not "some implementations". These are two separate requirements. The only case for the 100mA formal budgeting limit is only for a special class of "bus powered hubs",